# SSIS PowerShell Script EXECUTE

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, ssis, excel-2007

I am trying to open a protected excel file and re-save it without the password. I created a PowerShell script and it works if I manually set the executionpolicy to `remotesigned` or `unrestricted`.

I would like to not enable scripts but just bypass it through SSIS. I have tried a bunch of things the following is what I tried, but it does not work.

```
EXECUTE PROCESS TASK
Executable: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe
Arguement: -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "S:\PowerShell\UnlockExcel.ps1"
```

I have tried **-Command** instead of **-File** as well.

If I run the script after manually enabling scripts in PowerShell the script works so there is nothing wrong with the script, but if I put it back to restricted and try it with those arguments in SSIS it won't work.

Comment: I see S:\, is this a drive that would be available physically for the executing account or is it a mapped drive that a SYSTEM account or Service Account would have present?

Comment: Yeah its a mapped drive and it is available everywhere. I could try UNC path. I'll get back to you if it works.

Comment: That didn't work.. I added the unc path instead of S:\.. it gave me a exit code -196608...

And so i tried it with -Command instead if -File and that didn't give me anything it didn't bypass just reports success, but actually does nothing I believe it gave the cannot run script.

Comment: Can you create a simple ps1 script on the local disk that creates some `out-file` content to confirm the executing line is good, then move onto the UnlockExcel.ps1 file. Additionally I usually format my scheduled task jobs with the following arguments. `-NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File`

Comment: Hi can you put your comment as answer so I can tick it as an answer. the -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File worked.. no idea why it won't work without -NoLogo -NoProfile. Oh well atleast it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the executing line to include the following format.

```
-NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File
```

powershell.exe command line reference [TechNet Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Windows 2007 machine.I will update my answer when I deploy this on Server 2012 - I am hoping I don't have to reinvent the wheel again. MOre to come...

**Executable**: %windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe

**Arguments**: -NoProfile "C:\temp\scripts\vpn.ps1"